# Accessing values in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, python-3.3

Nested dictionary has a length of 12, this is one of the records:

```
{('ALEXANDER', 'MALE'): {'2010': ('2619', None), '2011': ('2494', None), '2009': ('2905', None)}, ...
```

Main key = `('ALEXANDER', 'MALE')`

Main value (which is nested dictionary) = `{'2010': ('2619', None), '2011': ('2494', None), '2009': ('2905', None)}`

Nested dictionary key/value = `'2010': ('2619', None)` ...

How would one access the year `'2010'` and the value `'2619'`?

Is it possible to do this using variables?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Hi, One of the expected outputs is to rank the names according to the year and count, (count = '2619' in the example). The "None" would become a rank like (1 , 2, 3 ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may point you in the right direction:

```
>>> d= {('ALEXANDER', 'MALE'): {'2010': ('2619', None), '2011': ('2494', None), '2009': ('2905', None)}}
>>> for mainKey in d:
    print(mainKey)
    for key,val in d[mainKey].items():
        print(key,val[0])


('ALEXANDER', 'MALE')
2011 2494
2009 2905
2010 2619
```

Answer (score 3):

If `D = {'2010': ('2619', None), '2011': ('2494', None), '2009': ('2905', None)}`

Then `D.keys()` return the list of keys in the dictionary `['2009', '2011', '2010']`

Then you can access to the value `2010` by `D.keys()[-1]` and to `2619` by `D[D.keys()[-1]][0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {
    ('ALEXANDER', 'MALE'): {'2010': ('2619', None), '2011': ('2494', None), '2009': ('2905', None)},
    # ...
}
value, _ = data[('ALEXANDER', 'MALE')]['2010']
```

Then `value = '2619'`

Answer (score 0):

When your dictionary's key is a tuple, I personally prefer to use the [namedTuple](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) function. This allows you access elements in the dictionary in a clean and readable way.

In the code below I present a way to use the namedTuple construct and some ways to access the elements further.

```
from collections import namedtuple

my_dict = {('ALEXANDER', 'MALE'): {'2010': ('2619', None), '2011': ('2494', None), '2009': ('2905', None)}}

person = namedtuple("Person", ["name", "sex"])
nt1 = person(name="ALEXANDER", sex="MALE")
print nt1.name
# outputs "ALEXANDER"
print nt1.sex
# outputs "MALE"
print my_dict[nt1]
# outputs {'2009': ('2905', None), '2011': ('2494', None), '2010': ('2619', None)}
print my_dict[nt1].keys()
# outputs ['2009', '2011', '2010']
print my_dict[nt1]['2010']
# outputs ('2619', None)
print my_dict[nt1]['2010'][0]
# outputs 2619
```